# How can I rotate my any view such as UIView, UITableview, UIScrollview from portrait to landscape through code?

Tags: iphone

How can I rotate my any view such as UIView, UITableview, UIScrollview from portrait to landscape through code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CGAffineTransform to rotate it:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
theView.transform = transform;
```